# Azure Policy to add multiple tag names and tag values

Tags: json, azure, tags, policy

Need to create an Azure Policy that would add multiple tag names and tag values

Need to assign a policy in Azure, where the resources are to be deployed only using the specified tag names and values.

```
{
   "properties": {
      "displayName": "Enforce tag and its value",
      "policyType": "BuiltIn",
      "description": "Enforces a required tag and its value.",
      "parameters": {
         "tagName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Name of the tag, such as costCenter"
            }
         },
         "tagValue": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
               "description": "Value of the tag, such as headquarter"
            }
         }
      },
      "policyRule": {
         "if": {
            "not": {
               "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
               "equals": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
            }
         },
         "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
         }
      }
   },
   "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/1e30110a-5ceb-460c-a204-c1c3969c6d62",
   "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
   "name": "1e30110a-5ceb-460c-a204-c1c3969c6d62"
}
```

The code describes how to add tag name and value for a single tag. 
Need to add more than one tag value and tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
"if": {
    "not": {
        "allOf": [
            {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName1'), ']')]",
                "equals": "[parameters('tagValue1')]"
            },
            {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName2'), ']')]",
                "equals": "[parameters('tagValue2')]"
            }
        ]
    },
    "then": {
       "effect": "deny"
    }
},
```

and you'd need 2 additional parameters as well.

Comment: What if we need to add a Tag name for which there can be multiple Tag values depending upon the scenario?

For Example,

Tag Name: Environment
Tag Value: Prod, Non-Prod, UAT, Test

So, here the Tag Name is same for all the values, and the values will change accordingly for different scenarios.

What could be the code for the same?

Comment: that would be a new question, if this answers your question accept it and start a new question. I'll gladly look into that one.

Comment: Yes, it did answer my question. Thanks.

Can you look into the below link as well for similar issue that was discussed later?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629219/azure-policy-to-add-tag-values-for-single-tag-name