# Azure Policy to add tag values for single tag name

Tags: json, azure, tags, resources, policy

Need to assign a policy in Azure, where the resources are to be deployed only using the specified tag names and values.
We need to add a Tag name for which there can be multiple Tag values depending upon the scenario.

For Example,

Tag Name: Environment

Tag Value: Prod, Non-Prod, UAT, Test

So, here the Tag Name is same for all the values, and the values will change accordingly for different scenarios. What could be the code for the same?

Comment: ok, sorry, I dont understand how is this different to the previous question?

Comment: I think this policy does what you're after: https://github.com/Azure/Community-Policy/blob/master/Policies/Tags/require-tag-and-value-from-set/azurepolicy.json.  It doesn't allow multiple tag values at the same time though (e.g. you can't tag the same resource as being shared by `UAT` and `TEST`, you'd have to create a value for that combo in the `allowedValues` list.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you my code, kinda similar situation with yours.. in my case this code works fine:

```
{
"properties": {
  "displayName": "Enforce Resource Group Tag Values",
  "policyType": "Custom",
  "mode": "All",
  "parameters": {
    "tagEnv": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Environment",
        "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
      }
    },
    "allowedEnv": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Allowed environments",
        "description": "The list of value that can be specified when deploying resources",
        "strongType": "environment"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "common",
        "dev",
        "test",
        "prod",
        "research"
      ],
      "defaultValue": [
        "common"
      ]
    }
  },
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagEnv'), ']')]",
                "exists": "false"
            },
            {
                "not": {
                    "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagEnv'), ']')]",
                    "in": "[parameters('allowedEnv')]"
                }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Azure Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview) Framework and there is built-in definition for your requirement- "Enforces existence of a tag. Does not apply to resource groups."

Steps to create assignment from portal is specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/assign-policy-portal).
This will not allow creation of resources without tag.
You can checkout more in built definitions from Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use Array parameters, and have a policy definition for each tag. I was trying to dynamically create one which can be used for different tags and then another option to specify multiple tag values, but couldn't make it work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/author-policies-for-arrays