# How to add dynamic multiple tag names and values to all the resources in azure using azure policy

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

Ask: My requirement is to add multiple tags to  all the resources in my subscription using azure policy. But the existing built in policies only adds multiple tag values to already hardcoded tag names. So, the tag names become static and only the values are dynamic.

Also my case do not have specified number of tags to be populated. Since they are dynamic I'm not able to use tagname1, value1 , tagname2, value2 ...etc in the operations modify effect.

I would like the policy to determine how many tags are being passed in and populate them in azure resource.

In this case, I tried the below. But did not work

```
    "effect": "modify",
    "details": {
      "roleDefinitionIds": [
        "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-    20f7382dd24c"
      ],
      "operations": [
        {
          "operation": "addOrReplace",
          "field": "[parameters('tagNames')]" 
          "value": "[parameters('tagvalues')]"

        }
      ]
```

The value of tagnames and tagvalues are in object defined in policy assignment and the number of tags is dynamic

`"Tagdetails": [ { "tagnames": "value1", "tagvalues":  1  }, { "tagnames": "value2", "tagvalues":  3  } {.......} ]`

From going through the ms documentation, I understand that count might be used to iterate the number of tags but I do not understand how to loop the effect and add all those tags in the resource

Comment: Someone already asked it. Go check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427380/azure-policy-to-add-multiple-tag-names-and-tag-values?rq=2

Comment: Hi @BarMinz, Thank you . I went through the link already and from the policy we can know that only defined number of tags can be added. If we want to add 5 tags, we need to create 5 variables from tagvalue 1 to 5. I'm looking for adding any number of tags dynamically where the policy definition will determine the number of tags passed in and loop accordingly

Comment: Azure Policies are not inherently designed to dynamically determine and loop through an arbitrary number of tags.

However, you can use the forAll property in a policy rule to iterate over an array of objects and perform an operation on each object.

Answer (score 0):

> My requirement is to add multiple tags to all the resources in my subscription using azure policy.

The below policy that adds multiple tags to all resources in subscription using the `addOrReplace` operation.

> Note:  Azure Policies are not inherently designed to dynamically determine and loop through an arbitrary number of tags. However, you can use the forAll property in a policy rule to iterate over an array of objects and perform an operation on each object

The policy rule checks if the `type` field exists, which is true for all resource types, so the policy will apply to all resources in subscription.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "type",
      "exists": "true"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "modify",
      "details": {
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName1'), ']')]",
            "value": "[parameters('tagValue1')]"
          },
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName2'), ']')]",
            "value": "[parameters('tagValue2')]"
          },
          {
            "operation": "addOrReplace",
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName3'), ']')]",
            "value": "[parameters('tagValue3')]"
          }
        ],
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/36243c78-bf99-498c-9df9-86d9f8d28608"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagName1": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name 1",
        "description": "Name of the first tag to add"
      }
    },
    "tagValue1": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Value 1",
        "description": "Value of the first tag to add"
      }
    },
    "tagName2": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name 2",
        "description": "Name of the second tag to add"
      }
    },
    "tagValue2": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Value 2",
        "description": "Value of the second tag to add"
      }
    },
    "tagName3": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name 3",
        "description": "Name of the third tag to add"
      }
    },
    "tagValue3": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Value 3",
        "description": "Value of the third tag to add"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Tag parameter**

[image]

Whenever I try to change the tag value from `High` to `Low` for a specific resource, the policy automatically replaces the value.

[image]

[image]

Refer the [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629219/azure-policy-to-add-tag-values-for-single-tag-name) by @`Heri Fauzan`